# .load() issues, loading from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

i have this form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="enviaorcamento.asp">
    <strong>Nome:</strong><input name="nome" type="text" class="formsahn" id="nome" size="50">
    <input name="enviar" type="submit" class="mensagem" id="enviar" value="enviar">
</form>
```

this content is loaded from another page into home.html inside the div `#conteudo_mostrar`

my jquery `.load()` script is that:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#conteudo_mostrar").load("form.asp");
    });
    function abrirPag(valor)
    {
    $("#conteudo_mostrar").load(valor).fadeIn("slow");
    }
</script>
```

and on the end on `enviaorcamento.asp` (my sending page) i have the script:

```
<script>alert('Orçamento Enviado com Sucesso!'); window.parent.$('#conteudo_mostrar').load('obrigadoorcamento.asp');</script>
```

but this not work.

i want load `obrigadoorcamento.asp` into `#conteudo_mostrar` from the sending page.

I hope i'm clear...

Comment: also, for `$("#conteudo_mostrar").load(valor).fadeIn("slow");`, you probably need to move `fadeIn` into `load`'s callback function. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I have used this to close some "lightbox" in another project, and i think this work.. but not... i dont know i'm right using this...

Comment: yeah. but this is not the problem. My problem is load `obrigadoorcamento.asp` inside `home.hmtl` in div `#conteudo_mostrar` from my ASP Sending Page...

Comment: You aren't catching the submit event of the form and the form is submitting to the current window. Your alert script will run well after the page has reloaded. You probably want to handle the form submit using a submit handler and ajax.

Comment: humm....so i need to use Ajax to send ...

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/load/ please check it and let us know. If it will not work, try to use $.get() and insert into DOM manually.

[image]

Comment: also try to check if **window.parent.$** exists? Would appreciate some jsfiddle script